# Auto read data from excel when data is modified

Tags: c#, excel

I am developing a `C#` application to read data from an `Excel` file. The file is updated from another application. I need to execute my `C#` code each time the `Excel` file is modified, read data from it, and process the data.

I searched and find codes to read data from `Excel`.

Is there any way by which I can execute my `c#` code when `Excel` file is modified? 
(like scheduling a job or something like that)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.filechangemonitor(v=vs.110).aspx. This'll  help,if you want to use caching

Comment: if you dont want to use caching you can always have a low priority thread which contniously reads the last file modified date and if the date changes then previous you can raise an event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FileSystemWatcher. 
It can fire an event when the file is updated.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher_events(v=vs.110).aspx

File Change Monitor class
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.filechangemonitor(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the `FileChangeMonitorClass`,you can use below code.

> In Below code I am checking the `last file modified date` every time in a continuous loop ,if the `date` is found different you can raise an event to handle that change,if you want to stop checking the file you can set the `m_isToKeepChecking` which is global to false.

```
Thread thr = new Thread((new ThreadStart(() => CheckFile())));
thr.Start();

bool m_isToKeepChecking = true;
private void CheckFile()
{
    DateTime previousTime = DateTime.Now;
    while(m_isToKeepChecking)
    {
        DateTime currTime = File.GetLastWriteTime("some Path");
        if(currTime >previousTime)
        {
           previousTime = currTime;
           //Raise your event to handle the change;
        }
    }
}
```